# Simple jhipster app builds and runs, but no admin interface generated

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, jhipster

I built a simple jhipster app to start a new Spring Application project from. I chose:

- Java 7
- Local Auth
- Postgresql both for production and development
- No HTTP sessions
- No Websocket
- Ehcache
- Maven
- Grunt

I created the relevant Schemas in Postgresql and started the app with `mvn spring-boot:run` in the terminal and I get a starting page for my application on localhost. Only the navigation is visible and none of the attached javascripts seems to be running or at least working properly. In the javascript log I get "ReferenceError: angular is not defined". None of the links take me anywhere.

Talking about logs, the startup says the app is using **org.jboss.logging**. I see no log files. Anyone knows where the logs are? I'm trying to read the source code for log settings, but I can't seem to find the proper settings.

There are no created tables in the database either.

I assume there is a setting I missed somewhere, but I don't have a clue yet. Hopefully I can find the logs soon and get one.

**Any ideas how to diagnose this problem is most welcome. Thank you.**

Comment: did you run grunt to install your js dependencies?

Comment: I did not. I'm a newbie to grunt. But in the jhipster video demo that didn't seem to be necessary to get the basic interface.

Comment: It appears that the jhipster generator adds dependencies. This is from the install: > "Running bower install & npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself." Trying that.